# Can I get my ruby terminal apps to run online?

Tags: ruby, heroku

To learn ruby, I've been making Tic Tac Toe Ais, Chess, checkers, etc.

I was thinking it would be excellent to be able to show a few mentors. Instead of asking them to run it in the console, is there a way to emulate the console and run the apps online, maybe on heroku?

Kind of a noob question, but would love to do this!

Comment: I'm not kind of sure about this answer so I will write it here, and if it fits your needs I can rewrite it as an answer. There is lot of online services that let you *run* ruby code. I was using www.c9.io . It has Ruby (and other languages) pre-installed. So you only clone workspace and run your code. After this you give link to others. There are *online compilers* but they don't support much of *console* but you can check it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a quick and easy way to do what you want would be the following:

> http://labs.codecademy.com/

You can have an online console and and a simple editor which you can share with a url at any time